# Initializing and using the functionality of a FragmentActivity from another Activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

Please give me your opinions on this..
I made an app with a GoogleMap fragment activity (MapsActivity) and two other Activities(MainActivity,MapsContainerActivity)
Main Activity is the home page with a ListView. Essentially, the ListView have an item which when clicked.. will start an intent to go to MapsContainerActivity..

Inside MapsActivity, I have an implementation for OnMapLongClick, simply to add a marker at the clicking position... it is totally functional if I directly start MapsActivity from the MainActivity, however, It's causing a NullPointerException when I try to access the functionality of the OnMapLongClick from MapsContainer Activity

Here's MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;

    //ListView stuff
    ListView locationsListView;
    static ArrayList<String> locationsList;

    double lat = 0;
    double lng = 0;

    protected void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        locationsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.locationsListView);

        locationsList = new ArrayList<>();
        locationsList.add("Add a new place...");

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,locationsList);

        locationsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        locationsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsContainerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("locationInfo",position);
                startActivity(intent);



            }

        });



        // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

    }

    public void getLocation(View view){
        if(lat != 0 && lng != 0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Latitude", lat);
            intent.putExtra("Longitude", lng);

            startActivity(intent);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Location not retrieved, try again!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {

            Log.i("Latitude",mLastLocation.getLatitude()+"");
            lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();

            Log.i("Longitude",mLastLocation.getLongitude()+"");
            lng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

}
```

Here's the MapsActivity.java:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener {


    public MapsActivity(Context context){

    }


    Geocoder geocoder;
    int selectedItem = -1;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    double lat = 10;
    double lng = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_container);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        lat = intent.getDoubleExtra("Latitude", 0);
        lng = intent.getDoubleExtra("Longitude", 0);

        selectedItem = intent.getIntExtra("locationInfo", -1);
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (selectedItem != 0 && selectedItem != -1) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 8));
        }
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 8));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        String label = new Date().toString();
        try {
            if (geocoder != null) {
                List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(point.latitude, point.longitude, 1);


                if (listAddresses != null && listAddresses.size() > 0) {
                    label = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(label == null){
            label = new Date().toString();
        }
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(point)
                .title(label)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
        Log.i("Latitude", " " + point.latitude);
        Log.i("Latitude", " " + point.longitude);
    }
}
```

Here's the MapsContainerActivity:

```
public class MapsContainerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapsActivity mapsActivity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_container);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        mapsActivity = new MapsActivity(this);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(mapsActivity);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);  // <--
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And btw, I created this MapsContainerActivity, because I wanted to **include** the MapsActivity fragment inside the MapsContainerActivity layout .. so I could add a Toolbar.

The error I am getting when I try to LongClick the map is here:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:114)
 at com.firashashash.myapplication.MapsActivity.onMapLongClick(MapsActivity.java:109)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$24.onMapLongClick(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzs$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
 at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bt.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:93)
 at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.ac.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:468)
 at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.af.d(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:700)
 at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.df.onLongPress(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:341)
 at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.gesture.g.onLongPress(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:179)
 at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.gesture.i.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:3579)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What stops you from creating the toolbar in MapsActivity?

Comment: Great news!!! I solved the problem...
What I did was simply ... I created a  `Geocoder` object and initialized it in **MapsContainerActivity's**  _onCreate()_ and as well as in **MapsActivity** then, I changed the **MapsActivity's constructor** to accept another parameter of type **Geocoder**, and then I passed the Geocoder object of MapsContainerActivity to MapsActivity and assigned it to the Geocoder object inside MapsActivity, then finally I removed the **geocoder** initialization from _onMapLongClick()_ method in MapsActivity

Comment: @HristoStoyanov I tried to do it, but I couldn't because it is a FragmentActivity, and I just don't know how to implement a **Toolbar** in it ... so I created a new layout, very similar to activity_main .. with a **CoordinatorLayout** and I included the layout which contains the map fragment

Comment: I have seen this error when using the Application context. Try using an `Activity` context.

Comment: Thank you @HristoStoyanov for bringing it to my mind, to put the functionality in one class ... I did do that and now it's working great!

Comment: Thanks @NaveenDissanayake for you answer, even though I didn't get exactly what you mean